Str.Contains in Pandas
I have a dataset as below where Coffee type = ['Robusta/Arabica','Arabica/Robusta','Arabia','Robusta']

How can I filter on rows which only contain 'Robusta'?
I tried to use str.contains('Robusta') but it includes 'Robusta/Arabica' and 'Arabica/Robusta'.

Your question isn't clear. Other than 'Robusta' what values should pass your test? If the answer is "none," why are you using contains() instead of ==?

Thank you, it's the answer that I'm looking for.

I have a tip for you, always use continuous strings to name pandas' dataframes columns. That way you won't face issues when calling the column name trying to manipulate the dataframe (so, use "coffee_type" instead of "Coffee type"). With that in mind you could do:
df.columns = ['country', 'coffee_type', '1990/91']

groups = df.groupby('coffee_type')

Now you have in "groups" a list of dataframes, for each type of coffee, and can get the desired dataframe doing:
df_robusta = groups.get_group('Robusta') 

Note that coffee_type is now the index of the "df_arabica" dataframe.
You could also do, for example:
df_robusta = df[df['coffee_type']=='Robusta']

That is basic slicing. You can do this without creating a new variable for the new dataframe.

Thank you very much, it's very helpful for beginner like me.
